# Randomized quicksort C#

Tags: c#, arrays, stack-overflow, quicksort, array-algorithms

I am trying to analyze the quick sort algorithm with a random pivot on C#. This is the code I am trying to test:

```
//begeeben.wordpress.com/2012/08/22/randomized-quick-sort-in-c/ using System; using System.Collections.Generic; using System.Text; using System.Diagnostics; class Quicksort {
    public static void RandomizedQuickSort(int[] input, int left, int right)
    {
        if (left < right)
        {
            int q = RandomizedPartition(input, left, right);
            RandomizedQuickSort(input, left, q - 1);
            RandomizedQuickSort(input, q + 1, right);
        }
    }
    private static int RandomizedPartition(int[] input, int left, int right)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        int i = (left + random.Next()) % (right-left+1);

        int pivot = input[i];
        input[i] = input[right];
        input[right] = pivot;

        return Partition(input, left, right);
    }
    private static int Partition(int[] input, int left, int right)
    {
        int pivot = input[right];
        int temp;

        int i = left-1;
        for (int j = left; j < right; j++)
        {
            if (input[j] <= pivot)
            {
                i++;
                temp = input[j];
                input[j] = input[i];
                input[i] = temp;
            }
        }

        input[right] = input[i+1];
        input[i+1] = pivot;

        return i;
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        Stopwatch stopWatch;
        int []array;
        int size = 10;
        for (int j = 1; j < 7; ++j)
        {
            stopWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            array = new int[size];
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) array[i] = random.Next(0, 300);
            stopWatch.Start();
            RandomizedQuickSort(array, 0, size-1);
            stopWatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Number of millisec to sort " + size + " elements: " + stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            size = size * 10;
        }
    } 
}
```

Everything is going fine until I try to sort an array of 10,000,000 elements. At that point I am getting a stack overflow exception. I have tried using smaller integers but this also leads me to stack overflow issues. It appears that when the code terminates, left and right are both equal to zero. However, wouldn't the Merge sort exception had caught this?

~Update: The issue is that the array size is so big that I have used up the entire Heap! To fix this, I had to switch from a recursive algorithm to an iterative one.

Comment: When you make a function call a bit of the stack gets allocated and doesn't get freed until the function exits. With recursion, you can easily eat up the stack this way (tail-recursion is the exception). [RuntimeHelpers.EnsureSufficientExecutionStack Method ()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.runtimehelpers.ensuresufficientexecutionstack.aspx) might help verify this.

Comment: You can implement an iterative version of the algorithm. Recursion should be avoided when implementing algorithms like qsort, fibonacchi, etc. recursion is great when you deal with recursive data types, like trees

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C# has a max stack size of 1Mb and you're using it all up. That's just a in-built limitation of recursive implementations.

You have 3 solutions:
1) Build an iterative version of the algorithm (most performant)
2) Increase your stack size, something like:

```
Thread T = new Thread(threadEntryPoint, stackSizeInBytes);
T.Start();
```

3) Limit your analysis to list sizes this algorithm can handle.